# Strange behavior from Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I have a strange bug with nodemailer , that's my code

```
await transporter.sendMail({

from: "noreply@myDomainName.com",

to: this.inputs.email,

subject: "Accessing your account",

html: emailTemplate

});
```

the email sent to my users from my personal account

myPersonalEmail@gmail.com not from noreply@myDomainName.com

I use my personal account in the transporter - but why considering it ?

here's the transporter configs
process.env.EMAIL_SENDING_CONFIG includes

> myPersonalEmail@gmail.com#myPersonalEmailPassword

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    service: "gmail",
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL_SENDING_CONFIG.split("#")[0],
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_SENDING_CONFIG.split("#")[1]
    }
});
```

By the way , this email noreply@myDomainName.com is not exist , if this related to the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass your custom domain inside your auth propriety as mentioned in nodmailer document   https://nodemailer.com/smtp/.

also you can't use a custom domain with a free account (FREE STMP)

So you need to configure a transporter with your custom domain info (host, port, user and password) You can find this info in the email configuration of your specific hosting provider.

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: 'something.yourdomain.com',
port: 465,
secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
auth: {
  user: 'username@mydomain.com', // your domain email address
  pass: 'password' // your password
}
});
```

Then you can go on and define the mail options:

```
 var mailOptions = {
    from: '"Bob" <bob@bobsdomain.com>',
    to: 'tom@gmail.com',
    subject: "Hello",
    html : "Here goes the message body"
  };
```

Comment: you mean I need to use something like Sendgrid , mailgun and these services ? , to be able to use custom domain

Comment: no, you need to add your custom domain auth inside your auth object `auth`, 
so if you want to use this email `noreply@myDomainName.com`
you should own it then you  go here `auth: {
  user: 'noreply@myDomainName.com', // your domain email address
  pass: 'password' // your password
}
`